# Detect browser language on a specific page and redirect or show another

Tags: wordpress, redirect, translation

I have Terms & Conditions on my English website and have four language translations already written (French, German, Spanish, Italian).

How can I show a different language or redirect to, for example, the French translation when a French user visits the Terms & Conditions?

I need the redirect for the Terms & Conditions and for the Privacy Policy only, the rest of the site is fine.

I have this code that I am dropping into the page but can't get it to work.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

var lang = getUrlParameter('lang');
var langcode = lang.split('-');

if (langcode[0] === 'fr') {
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/privacy-fr");
}
else if (langcode[0] === 'de') {
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/privacy-de");
}
else if (langcode[0] === 'it') {
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/privacy-it");
}
else if (langcode[0] === 'es') {
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/privacy-es");
}

</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The site is built in WordPress.

Comment: you seem to have modified or planned to modify the link to the privacy page to have something like `siteurl/privacy?lang=fr-FR`, from what i see in your javascript code. Why not simply have replaced it directly by `siteurl/privacy-fr` if the page is found at this url? (taking the french as example)

Comment: Sorry Kaddath, I am not sure what you mean, I have basically inherited this code and am not familiar with JavaScript. Is there any clarity you can offer?

Comment: Unfortunately it's getting late here and someone is waiting for me. But your javascript code actually does that, it searches for an URL parameter such as `?lang=fr-FR` and extracts the `fr` to create the redirection. So obviously it was planned to add this parameter to the URL to know which lang to redirect to. I was just saying that there is probably a simpler method by just modifying your privacy page link at the source..

Comment: No worries Kaddath, thanks for your input.